# Missing commas/delimiters in generated CSV file using CsvHelper library after moving application to new server

Tags: csv, ubuntu, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, csvhelper

I have been using the [CsvHelper library for .NET](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) and it's been working 100%, until I moved the application to a new server. On the new server, after I generate the CSV file, the delimiters/commas are missing from the file for some reason.

I did not change anything in the code, I simply moved the application to the new server.

The Dotnet Core versions on both servers are the exact same at **2.2.103**.

Here are the Ubuntu versions of both servers:

- Server where CSV file is generated correctly:

  - Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  - Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
  - Release:        16.04
  - Codename:       xenial
- Server where CSV file is missing commas/delimiters:

  - Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  - Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
  - Release:        18.04
  - Codename:       bionic

Here is an example of the differences in the correct and incorrect CSV files that are generated:

[image]

Any ideas as to why the CSV file might be missing the commas/delimiters? Could it be a mismatch in the Ubuntu versions or a formatting setting that needs to be set on the new Ubuntu server?

**EDIT**:

Function to write the CSV file:

```
public static void CreateDeliveryReportCsvFile(string filePath, List<DatabaseFunctions.ProblemModem> lineItems)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(lineItems);
    }
}
```

`ProblemModem` Class:

```
public class ProblemModem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeliveredDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Post your code and file samples as *text*, not images. Most likely you *didn't* specify the delimiters in which case CsvHelper used the culture's default. Different cultures use *different* delimiters. In France or Greece for example the delimiter is `;` because comma is the decimal separator.

Comment: ALso post how you tried to *read* the characters. The text on the right looks like UTF8 that was read using a single-byte codepage. That A is the first byte of a two-byte UTF8 sequence

Comment: I added the code snippets. Do you know if there is a way to set the delimiter when using the CsvHelper .NET library? I am unable to find it anywhere in their docs. I'm not sure what you mean by _reading_ the file, I just opened it with Notepad and Excel to see what was wrong. If it helps, our program uploads the CSV file to a Slack channel. I never see the generated file before it's uploaded to Slack. Maybe Slack does something to the file?

Comment: But then again, the files uploaded to Slack were right before, so it's not Slack. It's the formatting on the new server. I need to find out how to set the delimiter using the CsvHelper library (if that's possible)

Comment: Yes, it's described in the docs, in the `Configuration` page. If you want to generate real Excel files use Epplus. As for *reading* the file, if you try to read a UTF8 file as if it were ASCII or Latin1, the two-byte sequences will appear as two characters instead of one. The first byte in that seqence byte is that `A` you see.

Comment: I found this `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";`, going to try it now and see if it works. I am confident it's the issue, because I did not explicitly set the delimiter.

Comment: The language, encoding used to read/write files in Linux is controlled by the `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` and `LC_ALL`. environment variables. Make sure the settings are the same between machines .NET uses UTF16 internally though, and StreamReader/StreamWriter use UTF8 by default. If one of the servers *doesn't* use UTF8, it will read UTF8 text as two bytes. The strange thing though is that *comma* is part of US-ASCII and remains a single byte in UTF8.

Comment: Ok so setting the delimiter with `csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";` did work! Thanks Panagiotis. and thanks for pointing out about the environment variables, I never knew where to configure the those. I just did a check and saw that on the old server, the `LANG` was set to `en_US.UTF-8` and on the new server it was set to `en_ZA`. So am I right in saying that, if I changed the `LANG` on the new server so it's the same as on the old server, I would not have had this issue?

Comment: Yes. I just found something weird though. For `en-ZA` the CultureInfo object shows that `,` is the decimal *and* list separator, while the *group* (thousand) separator is `0xA0` ! That's the `NO-BREAK SPACE` character, which looks like a space but isn't. For `af-ZA` the list separator is `;`, the decimal separator `,` and the thousand separator is again the `NO-BREAK SPACE`

Comment: Alright awesome thanks! Haha yea that is strange. Well it seems to be working fine now, since I explicitly set the delimiter. Thank you for your assistance and information Panagiotis :)

Comment: Check [this relevant issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11221). The locale settings come from the OS and its libraries. If those libraries change from one version to another, or even if you update one of them, you *will* get different results from different versions of the same OS.

Comment: Oops! Looks like South African locales in Ubuntu are particularly troublesome [as this article explains](https://adrianfrith.com/decimal-comma-ubuntu/). Different formats used between `glibc` and Ubuntu. You may want to try some shell or C code to see what the OS thinks the separators are in each case, and what .NET Core thinks they are. They should be the same, affected the same way by the OS and libraries but .....

Comment: Wow you are actually on to something, Panagiotis. I never knew about this issue, thanks for sharing these resources with me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because the CsvHelper library made the somewhat questionable decision to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ListSeparator` as the [default separator](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/30b13339eb6adad447426bb6b48ed66cc4b7f679/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L20) instead of `','`. This means that the default separator is dependent on the configuration of the machine, and as you are seeing, the version of the installed OS. As you have probably figured out by now, you can fix this by assigning the delimiter explicitly.

For data interchange applications `InvariantCulture` would have been the better choice. Or, just hard-coding the default to comma.